# Elasticsearch 5.2.2: terms aggregation case insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, case-insensitive

I am attempting to do a case-insensitive aggregation on a keyword type field, but I'm having issues in getting this to work.

What I have tried so far is to add a custom analyzer called "lowercase" which uses the "keyword" tokenizer, and "lowercase" filter. I then added a field to the mapping called "use_lowercase" for the field I want to work with. I wanted to retain the existing "text" and "keyword" field components as well since I may want to search for the terms within the field.

Here is the index definition, including the custom analyzer:

```
PUT authors
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "lowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "famousbooks": {
      "properties": {
        "Author": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "use_lowercase": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "lowercase"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I add 2 records with the same Author, but with different case:

```
POST authors/famousbooks/1
{
  "Book": "The Mysterious Affair at Styles",
  "Year": 1920,
  "Price": 5.92,
  "Genre": "Crime Novel",
  "Author": "Agatha Christie"
}

POST authors/famousbooks/2
{
  "Book": "And Then There Were None",
  "Year": 1939,
  "Price": 6.99,
  "Genre": "Mystery Novel",
  "Author": "Agatha christie"
}
```

So far so good. Now if I do a terms aggregation based on Author,

```
GET authors/famousbooks/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "authors-aggs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Author.use_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [Author.use_lowercase] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "authors",
        "node": "yxcoq_eKRL2r6JGDkshjxg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [Author.use_lowercase] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [Author.use_lowercase] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

So it seems to me that the aggregation is thinking that the search field is **text** instead of **keyword**, and hence giving me the fielddata warning. I would think that ES would be sophisticated enough to recognize that the terms field is in fact a keyword (via custom analyzer) and therefore aggregate-able, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

If I add `"fielddata":true` to the mapping for Author, the aggregation then works fine, but I'm hesitant to do this given the dire warnings of high heap usage when setting this value.

Is there a best practice for doing this type of insensitive keyword aggregation? I was hoping I could just say `"type":"keyword", "filter":"lowercase"` in the **mappings** section but that is not available it seems.

It feels like I'm having to use too big of a stick to get this to work if I go the `"fielddata":true` route. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Turns out the solution is to use a custom normalizer instead of a custom analyzer.

```
PUT authors
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "myLowercase": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "famousbooks": {
      "properties": {
        "Author": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            },
            "use_lowercase": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "myLowercase",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This then allows terms aggregation using field `Author.use_lowercase` without issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is not possible by default,(without `"lowercase"` normalizer) but without this you can use a trick - translate the string in a case insensitive regex match.

e.g. for string `"bar"` - a case insensitive regex would be `"[bB][aA][rR]"`

I used a python helper for doing this:

```
def case_insensitive_regex_from_string(v):
    if not v:
        return v
    zip_obj = zip(itertools.cycle('['), v, v.swapcase(), itertools.cycle(']'))
    return ''.join(''.join(x) for x in zip_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you did define use_lowercase as text:

`"use_lowercase": {
   "type": "text",
   "analyzer": "lowercase"
}`

Try defining it as `type: keyword` - It helped me with a similar problem I had with sorting.

Comment: Unfortunately, specifying `type: keyword` instead of `type:text` fails if you also specify an analyzer as well (as I am doing here to get the lowercase piece to work).

Error message when setting up mapping:
Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [analyzer : lowercase]